# Remove locked file (locktype=Shared)

Tags: lock

there is a file I want to delete but it is locked.
I see with powershell that the lock type is **Shared**.

```
>$item = $web.GetListItem('pathtomyfile')
>$item.file.locktype
>Shared
```

Can I change or remove the locktype with Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the powershell script for removing/releasing lock from any document from SharePoint

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://intranet.contoso.com 
$list = $web.Lists["DocLib"] 
$item = $list.GetItemById(2) 
$file = $item.File 
$userId = $file.LockedByUser.ID 
$user = $web.AllUsers.GetByID($userId) 
$impSite= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $user.UserToken); 
$impWeb = $impSite.OpenWeb(); 
$impList = $impWeb.Lists[$list.Title] 
$impItem = $impList.GetItemById($item.ID) 
$impFile = $impItem.File 
$impFile.ReleaseLock($impFile.LockId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old post, but the same issue came up for us recently. We're on 2019 On-Prem and some files were randomly locked after migration.

I put this little powershell script together to just simply unlock all "shared" locked files.

```
## MULTI FILE UNLOCK
$LockType = "Shared" # Exclusive, Shared, None

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "https://yourWebApp.com"
foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites) {
    # Write-Host $siteColl.URL -b green
    foreach($web in $siteColl.AllWebs) {
        Write-Host $web.URL -b White
        foreach($list in ($web.Lists)) {
            write-host "The List title is "$list.Title -f Green
            foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                if ($item.File.LockType -clike $LockType) {
                    write-host "File Lock Type: "$item.File.LockType -b Red
                    write-host "File Path: "$item.Path
                    write-host "File Locked On: "$item.File.LockedDate
                    write-host "File Lock Expires on: "$item.File.LockExpires
                    $item.File.ReleaseLock($item.File.LockId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "End" -b DarkGreen -f Green
```

Hope this helps someone.